# JQuery validation plugin not accepting hypenated element name?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Does the JQuery validation plugin accept hyphens in the name? I'm getting syntax errors in my IDE when I have a hyphen in the name of the element I want to add rules to:

```
,rules: {
        Post-ImageFile: {
        accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png, image/gif"
        }
}
```

If I remove the hyphen I get no errors. Is this correct or is there something wrong with my IDE (Dreamweaver CS6)

Comment: javascript in general does not accept hyphens in object keys, so yes, that is a syntax error !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `"Post-ImageFile"` instead.

Comment: @JakeBurkhead If you look at the issue in the question, this does solve the syntax error.